# how can i set a livewire property before finishing a whole method?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am making a chat implemented ChatGPT with laravel livewire, I was trying to delete the variable of the message that the user writes after pressing enter and before starting the whole process of the method where I am saving the message and querying chatGPT, but the message input is not deleted until the whole process of saving and querying is finished.

This is the input

```
<input type="text" id="messageInput" wire:model.defer="message" wire:keydown.enter="sendMessage">
```

This is the code of the method in the component

```
    public function sendMessage()
{
    if ($this->message == '')
        return;
    
    $message = $this->message;
    $this->reset('message');
    // $this->message = '';
    // $this->emit('message.sent');

    $this->risco->chats()->create([
        'mensagem' => $message,
        'tipo' => Chat::TIPO['user'],
    ]);

    $this->getChats();
    $this->responseChatGPT($message);
}
```

try using  `$this->reset('message');` y `$this->message = '';`
also try using an event

```
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            Livewire.on('message.sent', () => {
             document.getElementById('messageInput').value = '';
            });
        });
```